# Deserialize Single Dimension JSON Array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, deserialization

assuming below multiple `single-dimensional` JSON Array:

```
{
    "F" : [ "FG3D2", "FG492", "FG4Q2", "FG562", "FG5Y2", "FG6C2" ],
    "M" : [ "MG3D2", "MG492", "MG4Q2", "MG562", "MG5Y2", "MG6C2" ],
    "N" : [ "NG3D2", "NG492", "NG4Q2", "NG562", "NG5Y2", "NG6C2" ],
    "P" : [ "PG3D2", "PG492", "PG4Q2", "PG562", "PG5Y2", "PG6C2" ]
}
```

what is the appropriate class design that could be used to deserialize it ? deserialization with JSON.Net and JavascriptSerializer() works when deserializing as `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` but i can't seem to find the appropriate Class that is equivalent for this.

below is the class design i am trying to base the deserialization with but fails:

```
public class Element
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to change your json, you want `{ Key:"F", Value:[]}`

Comment: but how do i align it so that the class adapts to the json ? instead of the json adapting to the class.

Comment: Btw, this is a helpful tool for JSON to POCO generation: [http://json2csharp.com/](http://json2csharp.com/). Not perfect but it is good for experimentation purposes.

Comment: can you please convert your comment as an answer ? you really saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Really you need to change your json. As it stands you'll need a class something like

```
public class Element
{
    public List<string> F {get; set;}
    public List<string> M {get; set;}
    ....
}
```

To populate your existing class structure your json should be:

```
[
  {"Key":"F", "Value":["FG3D2", "FG492", "FG4Q2", "FG562", "FG5Y2", "FG6C2" ]},
  {"Key":"M", "Value":["MG3D2", "MG492", "MG4Q2", "MG562", "MG5Y2", "MG6C2"]},
]
```

this makes more sense to me than what you have at the moment

Comment: while it does make sense, the json values are pre-processed on a separate api which i do not have any control of. that is why, i was looking for a way that my class would be the one to adapt.

Comment: which is fine, so you want the first option then

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your JSON to make this work. You have to make a list of key/value pairs:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "F",
        "Value": [ "FG3D2", "FG492", "FG4Q2", "FG562", "FG5Y2", "FG6C2" ]
    },
    {
        "Key": "M",
        "Value": [ "MG3D2", "MG492", "MG4Q2", "MG562", "MG5Y2", "MG6C2" ]        
    },
    {
        "Key": "N",
        "Value": [ "NG3D2", "NG492", "NG4Q2", "NG562", "NG5Y2", "NG6C2" ]
    },
    {
        "Key": "P",
        "Value": [ "PG3D2", "PG492", "PG4Q2", "PG562", "PG5Y2", "PG6C2" ]
    }
]
```

Then you can convert it as follows:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(json);
```

Where `RootObject` is:

```
class RootObject
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<string> Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

```
    var dic = JsonDeserializer<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);

    var els = new List<Element>();
    foreach(var k in dic.Keys)
    {
        els.Add(new Element { Key = k, Value = dic[k] });
    }
```

now you have your desired object.

Comment: The disadvantage of this is that you have to iterate the results which is obviously not very efficient.

Comment: you are right. but i don't think there is a way to directly convert your json to your desired one. they basically two different objects.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can create a class inherited from the dictionary:

```
public class Element : Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{ }
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as what he says he doesn't want?